# NSURLConnection Return Cached Response Even After Resetting Authorization Heder

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlconnection, httprequest, httpresponse

So this is the use case.

1. Application Run, Authorization Header is set to nil. You get fresh data.

   [_request setValue:nil forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
2. User login, After that all the requests to server are send with Authorization Header like this.

   [_request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"TRUEREST username=%@&session_token=%@&apikey=1234567890",@"username",@"session_token"]
          forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
3. Now I log out and now every request goes with Authorization Header nil value.

   [_request setValue:nil forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];

But I am still getting response as if I am logged in user? Any idea what's the issue?

Request to the server is made using as follows

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:_request
                                           queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
                               completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {}];
```

I have tried to make NSMutableURLRequest in following 2 ways.

```
    _request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    _request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url
                                                                cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadRevalidatingCacheData
                                                            timeoutInterval:60];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might disable the use of cookies before you use the request:

```
[_request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO];
```

Alternatively, delete any cookie - or the relevant cookie - form the `NSHTTPCookieStorage` singleton.

However, you could greatly improve your code using `NSURLConnection` implementing the delegate  `connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:` where you are able to fully customize authentication handling.

Comment: Thanks. It has fixed the issue.

Comment: Sure, you can use the delegate method and implement any detail and any custom behavior you want - as long as it conforms to the HTTP protocol.

Comment: [_request setHTTPShouldHandleCookies:NO]; did the trick for me. Thanks.

Comment: hay man, thanks for your help. I think I need your help again :). The issue has kind of returned. Now when I have moved to https and it is happening when I try to make 2 consecutive calls.

Comment: This is expected behavior. Establishing the initial SSL/TSL connection  requires to perform a handshake protocol which is somewhat elaborate and costly in terms of CPU and time. Thus, the TLS protocol allows a secure way to shortcut this process: "Resumed TLS Handshake". This allows the connection to use a "Session ID" or "Session Ticket" which identifies the session. _How exactly_ NSURLConnection utilizes these options in its _convenient methods_ is only vaguely known - but for sure it does use it. AFAIK, the only way to customize this is implementing the delegate methods of NSURLConnection.

Comment: More details in a TN from Apple: [TLS Session Cache](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1727/_index.html).  Read the warnings *carfully*!

Comment: Man you have saved my ass again. How I can pay you back for your great help. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1727/_index.html have wonderful workarounds. Thanks. Is there any way I can give you all of my SO points? :)

Comment: LOL,  thanks! ;)  BTW, there are a couple of related bug reports and feature request about this issue. I've asked a question on the dev forum specifically about clearing the TLS cache in iOS 7 (https://devforums.apple.com/thread/202466?tstart=0). Let's see how it goes. Quinn is usually answering very competently.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a server problem. The server should send response header telling the URL loading system to not cache the response.

Comment: The client may specify particular cache headers, and the server may respond accordingly. Proxies are involved, too. One cannot say generally, that this is a server problem without having a look at the packet trace.